# Is it possible remove bulk orphaned SID's from bulk ACL group using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, sid

I have tried the following One liner script

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "acl_security_temp" -Members "S-1-5-21-36468863-560803864-1537874043-13739"
```

but PowerShell would not detect the SID and returns error:

```
Cannot find an object with identity: 'S-1-5-21-36468863-560803864-1537874043-13739'
under: 'DC=XXXXXX,DC=YYYYY,DC=net'
```

Is there a possibility in PowerShell to develop a script to remove all orphaned SID's from bulk ACL groups?

Comment: Of necessity, this site is not a free code-generating service. With that said: What attempts have you made to solve this problem on your own (what does your code that removes orphaned SIDs look like so far)?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart OP provided their attempt

Comment: @Yaksh, are you sure these are orphaned SIDs on Active Directory object ACLs? It's expected to have to clean up orphaned SIDs on non-domain controllers (e.g. removing a domain user SID added explicitly to a local admin group on application servers once the user is removed from the domain) but seeing orphaned SIDs on objects while using ADUC could mean something is wrong with your AD replication. Removing the SIDs would be dangerous in this scenario without first resolving the replication issue.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest The question essentially says: "I tried this command and it didn't work - can someone develop code for me that does work?" As noted, that's not really the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart from reading the post, it seems the OP is asking if it is possible to develop a PS script to do this, not for someone to do it for them. They have also, quite clearly, provided some examples of their workings. I was under the impression that this was a site providing help and guidance which is exactly what the OP is asking for in this instance, not a site where questions are shut down because they don't meet some members' expectations. Please be helpful, not critical.

Comment: In my opinion, the question "is this possible" a bit pointless, because if the answer is "yes," then what's the implied next question ("OK, then how?"). My intent was not to be critical but to point out that SO is better suited to answering specific, targeted questions rather than generalized "is this possible" kinds of questions. I read the question again, and it still reads like a "can someone design a fully working solution for me?" kind of question, which is really out of scope for a site like this.